# MySQL query to find time difference based on a condition

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

**Mysql version 5.7.28**

I have a db with data in the below format

```
Id     ign     sp    time 
1       1      25    10:00
2       1      22    10:01
3       1      0     10:02
4       1      0     10:03
5       1      0     10:04
6       1      0     10:05
7       1      0     10:06
8       1      8     10:07
9       1      25    10:08
10      1      22    10:09
11      1      0     10:10
12      1      0     10:11
13      1      0     10:12
14      1      0     10:13
15      1      8     10:14
16      1      10    10:15
```

I need to design a query that will give me the result based on the condition
Ign =1 and sp =0 and the time difference between time where sp is consecutively 0. In this case, sp=0 between time 10:02 to 10:06 and 10:10 to 10:13.

Desired output:

```
Sp Start Time  Sp Stop Time
10:02          10:06 
10:10          10:13
```

Comment: Mysql version 5.7.28-0

Comment: You should get MySQL version 8 - it has Analytic functions which are great for this sort of query!

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @RickJames I need a resultant table to be 
Sp Start Time     Sp Stop Time
      10:02                    10:06
      10:10                    10:13

Comment: Are the minutes consecutive?  Or may I give you this "equivalent output:   10:01 10:01 --  10:09 10:14 ?

Comment: @RickJames That would be fine too. 10:01 - 10:07 and 10:09 - 10:14 would be fine too

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT MIN(`time`) time_from,
       MAX(`time`) time_till
FROM ( SELECT *, 
              @group := @group + CASE WHEN NOT sp AND @prev THEN 1 ELSE 0 END group_num, 
              @prev:=sp
       FROM test, (SELECT @prev:=-1, @group:=0) variable
       WHERE ign = 1
       ORDER BY `time` ) temp
WHERE NOT sp
GROUP BY group_num;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9870702e08d1bb4a6768050fff432cbe)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach I would try...

Step 1:  build a column with consecutive sequence numbers.  There at least 4 ways to do that

- Use the "times", since they seem to be consecutive
- @variables
- `AUTO_INCREMENT` (via a extra table)
- MariaDB (which you are not using) and its nifty "sequence" engine

Add an index to that column, which I will name `seq`.

Step 2: Now you can align two copies of the table thus, by something like `WHERE a.seq = b.seq + 1`

```
1000  25  1001 22
1001  22  1002  0   -- Since 22 > 0 and 0 = 0, it is the start of a gap
1002   0  1003  0
...
1006   0  1007 11   -- Since 0 = 0 and 11 > 0, it is the end of a gap 
1007  11  1008 24
1008  24  1009  0   -- an edge case: start of a 1-row gap
1009   0  1010 15   -- rest of that edge case
1010  15  ...
```

Step 3  A suitable WHERE clause gives you just

```
1001  22  1002  0   -- Since 22 > 0 and 0 = 0, it is the start of a gap
1006   0  1007 11   -- Since 0 = 0 and 11 > 0, it is the end of a gap 

1008  24  1009  0   -- an edge case: start of a 1-row gap
1009   0  1010 15   -- rest of that edge case
```

Step 4  Now comes another tricky pass over the data to combine the pairs in order to get the gap ranges:

```
1002 - 1006
1009 - 1009
```

I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader, but it may involve building another sequence number so you can identify the rows in each pair.